# C preprocessor flow control depending on function arguments

Tags: c, arguments, c-preprocessor, control-flow

What I want to do is something like this

```
#define TRIPLE_LOOP(code)\
//if there is something in code \
for(...) for(...) for(...) { code }\
//if code is empty then\
SOME_OTHER_CODE
```

so that

```
TRIPLE_LOOP(printf("muhahaha"))
```

will produce the printf inside a triple loop on the output
and

```
TRIPLE_LOOP()
```

will produce SOME_OTHER_CODE
Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

This almost works for me :)

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NARGS2(_1, N, ...) N
#define NARGS(...) NARGS2(__VA_ARGS__, 1, 0)
#define TRIPLELOOP(...)                         \
      do {                                      \
        if (NARGS(__VA_ARGS__)) {               \
          int i, j, k;                          \
          for (i=0; i<2; i++) {                 \
            for (j=0; j<2; j++) {               \
              for (k=0; k<2; k++) {             \
                __VA_ARGS__;                    \
              }                                 \
            }                                   \
          }                                     \
        } else {                                \
          printf("NO ARGS");                    \
        }                                       \
      } while (0)

int main(void) {
  TRIPLELOOP(printf("haha"); puts("!"));
  TRIPLELOOP();
}
```

It also [works at ideone](http://ideone.com/8j2aj).

Comment: @Hasturkun: it's horrible indeed; and the `else` is never executed. Yet, I am trying to come up with an even more horrible solution where the `else` also works :)

Comment: I got it to work using a GNU CPP extension of using the `##` token paste operator. `#define NARGS2(_1, _2, N, ...) N`, and `#define NARGS(...) NARGS2(, ##__VA_ARGS__, 1, 0)`. could probably be simplified though.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't do this. The value of "code" is defined at run time, while the macro is replaced on compile time. You have to use different macro definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you cannot do that because macro can be defined only once. You can use some trick to achieve that:

```
#define TRIPLE_LOOP(CONDITION, ...)\
if(CONDITION) {\
for(...) for(...) for(...) { __VA_ARGS__; }\
} \
else {\
SOME_OTHER_CODE \
}
```

Usage:

```
TRIPLE_LOOP(true, printf("muhahaha"));  // `true` can be 1
TRIPLE_LOOP(false);  // `false` can be 0
```

But make sure that you always pass a proper `bool` variable `true`/`false` while passing argument.

Answer (score 0):

If your compiler is gcc or MSVC, the following code might meet the purpose.

```
#define EXPAND( x ) x /* for MSVC */
#define CONCAT_( x, y ) x ## y
#define CONCAT( x, y ) CONCAT_( x, y )
#define CAR_( x, ... ) x
#define CAR(...) EXPAND( CAR_( __VA_ARGS__ ) )
#define VA_ARGS_(...) , ##__VA_ARGS__
#define VA_ARGS(...) VA_ARGS_( __VA_ARGS__ )
#define IS_EMPTY(...) CAR( VA_ARGS( __VA_ARGS__ ) 1 )

#define TRIPLE_LOOP(...) \
  CONCAT( TRIPLE_LOOP_, IS_EMPTY(__VA_ARGS__) )(__VA_ARGS__)
#define TRIPLE_LOOP_1(...) SOME_OTHER_CODE
#define TRIPLE_LOOP_(...) for(...) for(...) for(...) { __VA_ARGS__; }
```

`TRIPLE_LOOP_1` corresponds to empty argument case, and `TRIPLE_LOOP_`
corresponds to other cases.
Here is a test on [ideone](http://ideone.com/yHdPu).

Answer (score -1):

You can do this:

```
#define TRIPLE_LOOP(code)\
for(...) for(...) for(...) { code }\

#define TRIPLE_LOOP()\
SOME_OTHER_CODE
```

And i think it will work:)

Comment: And why not? TRIPLE_CODE(<smth>) isn't TRIPLE_CODE(). Also you can #define A(p1,p2,p3), #define A(p1,p2), #define A(p1) etc

Comment: nope :( it gives
    test.c:5:1: warning: "FUN" redefined
    test.c:3:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
    test.c:8:17: error: macro "FUN" passed 1 arguments, but takes just